# Pipeline job failing with message {Pending Description} only but works while I run that job only

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Pipeline configured with multiple jobs around 15-16. moved that pipeline from mercurial to git with Xcode 9.  only one job is failing with message {Pending description}, when I quit that job no console output is available for me.
Using jenkins 1.564. Do I need to update jenkins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deleted jobs & created new one with identical functionality and it works for me.